# How to add horizontal space between the question number and the actual question in exam document class

Tags: exam

I'm new to LaTeX but want to use it to set test papers.

My current code outputs my exam questions like this.

[image]

However, I want to increase the horizontal spacing between the question number and the question, as well as the option number and the option. I managed to achieve it somewhat by manually adding in `\hspace{0.2cm}`.

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to change it such that I don't need to manually input `\hspace{0.2cm}` every time? Such as changing the command of `\question` itself. Is that possible?

My current code is as follows:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
 
\setmainfont{Arial}
\title{Sample Exam}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
   
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\textbf{\thechoice}}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{\thequestion}}

\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}

\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\textbf{(\thesubpart)}}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.2cm}%
}

\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.4in}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{2em}}
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{1em}}
\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  
    \question \hspace{0.2cm}
    Which statement about $\ce{^{35}_{17}Cl}$ and $\ce{^{37}_{17}Cl}$ is correct?
    \begin{choices}
        \choice \hspace{0.2cm} They have the same number of electrons and protons.
        \choice \hspace{0.2cm} They have the same number of neutrons and electrons.
        \choice \hspace{0.2cm} They have the same number of neutrons and protons.
        \choice \hspace{0.2cm} They have the same number of nucleons and electrons.
    \end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `\leftmargin` is set before `\questionhook`, so changing `\labelsep` is too late.  OTOH, the drefault is `\settowidth{\leftmargin}{10.\hskip\labelsep}`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the user manual, the environments `questions` and `choices` are implemented as LaTeX `list` environments and you can set the list parameters by using the corresponding `\...hook` commands.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
 
\setmainfont{Arial}
\title{Sample Exam}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
   
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\textbf{\thechoice}}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{\thequestion}}

\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}

\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\textbf{(\thesubpart)}}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
  \addtolength{\labelsep}{0.2cm}}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \addtolength{\labelsep}{0.2cm}}

\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.4in}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{1em}}
\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  
    \question
    Which statement about $\ce{^{35}_{17}Cl}$ and $\ce{^{37}_{17}Cl}$ is correct?
    \begin{choices}
        \choice They have the same number of electrons and protons.
        \choice They have the same number of neutrons and electrons.
        \choice They have the same number of neutrons and protons.
        \choice They have the same number of nucleons and electrons.
    \end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```